# User Emulation for app testing in Dynamics 365

Tags: testing, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, ui-testing, dynamics-crm-365

In the Service Now platform there is a feature that emulates users. Is there a one in Dynamics 365 ? As of now, I am opening multiple tabs in different browsers to test user apps/forms/solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No out of the box feature for this.

Couple of ideas;

1. Use Firefox in conjunction with [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/). This allows you to effectively have multiple active sessions for different users open within a single browser. This might be easier to manage.
2. Use a single user, but write code to automate the switching of security roles. This way you can rapidly switch between different user roles.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do User experience emulation of different persona by OOB or with community tools. Only way is different browser window with different credentials (In-cognito or Run as different user).

Only simulator available is in Form editor - Preview option, to see how the Form looks-like with Tab/Section/Fields in Create/Update/Read-Only mode for Desktop Client.

[image]

With some Chrome Addins, we can impersonate a different user only on Unified Interface (UCI) not on web UI. [Read more](https://bguidinger.com/blog/user-impersonation-in-unified-interface-apps)

> Essentially, we just need to add the MSCRMCallerID header to every API request.  One way to do this is using the "ModHeader" extension for Google Chrome.  Once you have it installed, create a new profile to add the header to all requests for your environment.  It should look something like this...the MSCRMCallerID is the GUID of the user you want to impersonate.